# ESP32 and wifi router

Tags: wifi, esp32

I connected my ESP32 to Wifi and I can see this in my Wireless Statistics:

```
ID |       MAC Address      |Current Status| Packets Received | Packets Sent | SSID
1  | 3C: 71: BF: 0D: CB: 00 | Connected    |         52       |       47     |mySSID
```

I can ping via IP but I can't see ESP device in the DHCP list or ARP.
Could you explain why? And how I can fix this?

Comment: where does the statistics info come from? ... how are you performing the DHCP list and the ARP? ... please update your question to make it clear what you did ... as it stands, it appears that the question is not related to the Arduino

Answer (score 1):

I made a binding IP and MAC and now I see my ESP)

Comment: how did you do the binding?